# connect esxi to ceph

Tags: ceph

I want to connect `ceph` to `esxi`

My version of `ceph` is `mimic`.

I've searched a lot and found [this](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/mimic/rbd/iscsi-initiator-esx/)

My health of `ceph` is OK. I want to know how can I install `iscsi` gateway on my `ceph`

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

A "iSCSI initiator" (ESXi server) must have a "iSCSI target" (disk) that it can talk to.

In your case the "iSCSI target" is the "iSCSI gateway" in Ceph.

The configuration is in the documentation you mentioned under the menu "Configuring the iSCSI Target" in the URL below.

Ref.: http://docs.ceph.com/docs/mimic/rbd/iscsi-target-cli/

Comment: i see that link before but it did not help  . do you try it before